# Composer is not copying on the specified bin-dir directory

Tags: php, json, composer-php

I had this issue sometimes, on windows, on mac, on ubuntu...

I have this composer.json:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "zizaco/confide": "~4.0@dev",
    "zizaco/entrust": "1.2.*@dev",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.4",
    "behat/behat": "3.0.12",
    "behat/mink": "1.5.0",
    "behat/mink-extension": "2.0.0",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "1.0.9",
    "codeception/verify": "0.2.7",
    "codeception/specify": "0.3.6"

},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin/",
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

}

This is Laravel 4 with a few testing packages.

After a composer install or a composer update the directory "bin" is not created on my project.

I should have one binary for phpunit and another for behat. So i have to use the commands like vendor/behat/bin/behat and vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit which is a pain.

Any idea why the binaries are not on the "bin" folder?

Yesterday, the some project with less packages, I had the binary folder there with the phpunit binary. Now is gone. I don't get it.

Comment: Probably no writing rights on the root folder !

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me today as well. While I haven't yet figured out why it happens, a dirty workaround is to remove `vendor` folder and run `composer install`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this pull request in composer's git repo:
https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/5127

It seems that the feature of recreating the binaries, will get released in Composer 1.1